# firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler not triggered when app is in background

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I assumed I followed all the steps to handling background notifications from firebase in flutter. I have created a **top-level** function that I am expecting to be triggered whenever a notification comes in. However, the function is never triggered.

Here's the top-level background handler function that exists in my home page widget but outside the class:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // ignore: avoid_print
  print('A background message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');

  // update SQLite
  var result = await PageService.instance
      .add(PageService.instance.convertToPage(message.data));
  print('added to db: ${result}');
}
```

Here is my home page init state that calls a function to initialize firebase messgaging:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeFirebaseMessaging();
  }
```

And then here is the _initializeFirebaseMessaging function that is defined in the home page class as well:

```
void _initializeFirebaseMessaging() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('new notification arrived');
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      // update SQLite
      var result = await PageService.instance
          .add(PageService.instance.convertToPage(message.data));
      print('added to db: ${result}');

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        // show notification
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
  }
```

The onmessage.listen works fine as I get notificationd and handle them while I'm in the app, but the background handler is not triggered at all.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you plz print only `print('A background message just showed up')` to start with? So that we know if THAT functions...

Comment: And I agree with another answer, `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` should not be there, because this function is supposed to be triggered while the app is NOT bound... So speaking of that, plz put your print statement FIRST in the function! So that you'll know if it was at all triggered, even if something went wrong later.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage inside your main() not in initState()

Comment: I was thinking that too... It's what I do, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

`onMessage` handles foreground notification

`onMessageOpenedApp` handles background notification

Instead of using `onMessage` for handling Background notifications, add another function block of `FirebaseMessaging` with `onMessageOpenedApp`, if you want notification while the app is in **background**, like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message){...})
```

`onMessage` only works when the app is in foreground.
If you want notification while the app is in the **terminated** state you can use:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message){...})
```

Update your `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` to this:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  // ignore: avoid_print
  print('A background message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');

  // update SQLite
  var result = await PageService.instance
      .add(PageService.instance.convertToPage(message.data));
  print('added to db: ${result}');
}
```

And finally, the **main()** should look like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Add Firebase Initialization:
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // This will initialize a new Firebase instance.

  // Background message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  
  runApp(const App());
}
```

You should call `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);` from within **main()**, not from Homepage `initState(){}`.

Comment: You can't use `onMessageOpenedApp` instead of `onMessage`! onMessageOpenedApp is only triggered when the app was literally opened because a user clicked a notification, which is a very different scenario from when a message comes in while the app is in foreground, which is when onMessage is fired! (The latter case doesn't even automatically produce a notification.) Otherwise, this is a great answer with lots of good tips. 

Comment: Also `getInitalMessage` is meant to tell the app what to do when it was opened by clicking a notification while the app was in terminated. I.e. the notification is already there! (As for `onMessageOpenedApp`.) This function only makes sure the app gets the data from the notification, so that it can do stuff with it.

Comment: I see, I wasn't clear enough! What I meant was, use `onMessageOpenedApp` besides `onMessage` if he wants both foreground and background notification. Lemme update the answer!

As for the `getInitialMessage` description you gave, I didn't know it worked like that. Thank you so much, maam!

Comment: Ok, but `onMessageOpenedApp` works very much THE SAME as `getInitialMessage`... You can see, for example, that they both take a message as an argument! The only difference is that the former is triggered when app wakes up from background, whereas the latter is triggered when app wakes up from terminated.

Answer (score 0):

try: after main func

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  ...
}
```

and remove **WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();** in **firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler**